# C: Sort vector elements in descending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, vector

I am trying to create a function that will rearrange an array so it is in descending order. The array is made up from positive integers, with no two equal elements. This is what I have:

```
int check (int *v, int n){
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    if (v[i] != -1){
        return -1;
        break;
    }
    else return 1;
}
}

void sortVector (int *v, int n){
    int i, k, j=0, vp[n];

while (check(v,n) == -1){   
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (k=i+1; k<n; k++){
            if (v[k] > v[i]) break;
            else if (k == n-1){
                vp[j] = v[i];
                v[i] = -1;
                j++;
            }               
        }
    }
}

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    v[i] = vp[i];
}
```

Which is not working correctly. I've been thinking about this for the past week so some pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `check` always  return the first element.

Comment: Where is your `main`? What is the idea behind the sorting algorithm? It's kind of hard to deduce it

Comment: what kind of sorting algorithm are you trying to implement ?

Comment: if all the integers are positive in the array so why in `check()` function are you comparing them to `-1` ??

Comment: Actually I made a mistake when asking the question, I really meant descending not ascending. The sortVector() function finds the maximum of vector v, copies it to vp and replaces it in vector v with -1. That's why I use  the check() function: the idea is that when it is done all elements of v will be -1, the program will get out of the while loop, and will copy vp to v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow **the idea that you have stated in your comment** by starting from your code above and made few changes and here is the two final functions

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check (int *v, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (v[i] != -1)
        {
            return -1; // break is useless because return has the same effect 
        }
    }
    return 1; // you need to add a return here to handle all the cases
              // the case if the loop is not entered you need to return a value 
}

void sortVector (int *v, int n)
{
    int i, k, j=0, vp[n];
    int maxIndex=0;//you need to add this variable in order to keep track of the maximum value in each iteration

    while (check(v,n) == -1)
    {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            maxIndex=i; //you suppose that the maximum is the first element in each loop 
            for (k=i+1; k<n; k++)
            {
                if (v[k] > v[maxIndex])
                  maxIndex=k; // if there is another element greater you preserve its index in the variable 
            }
           //after finishing the loop above you have the greatest variable in the array  which has the index stored in maxIndex
                    vp[i] = v[maxIndex]; // put it in vp array
                    v[maxIndex]=v[i];//put it in treated elements zone
                    v[i]=-1;// make it -1
                    j++;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        v[i] = vp[i];
}
```

This is the test

```
int main()
{
    int tab[]= {1,152,24,11,9};
    sortVector (tab, 5);
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",tab[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which gives the desired output

```
152 24 11 9 1
```

Note: You can improve your code by making swaps on the same array instead of allocating another array !

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I didn't remember this - I've used temporary variables to find maximum values lots of times before. What I'm not getting is the difference between doing just `v[maxIndex]=-1` and `v[maxIndex]=v[i]; v[i]=-1;`, like you have done, after you find the maximum

Comment: let's take the example of  `v[]= {1,152,24,11,9};` for the first loop `i=0` we have `v[0]=1` and the maximum is `152` so if you turn `152` into `-1` you will have `1 -1 24 11 9` in the next loop( I mean for `i=1`)  you will ignore the first element which is `1` here  that 's why you need to swap between `v[i]` and v[maxIndex]` the maximum with the first element (like this `152 1 24 11 9` ) after that turn it into `-1` (like this `-1 1 24 11 9`) so `1` can be included the sorting algorithm of the next loops

Comment: If you still need explanation feel free to ask please @mcpca ! :)

Comment: Yes, I get it - that also seems to render my already dubious check() function useless, which makes it even simpler. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There are really lots of algorithms for sorting. A simple algorithm is to find the minimum element in your array and put it in the first position by swapping it with whatever item was in the first position and then recursively sorting the array but this time starting at the next position.

```
void sort(int a[], int l, int r)
{   if(l == r) return; /* 1-elemnt array is already sorted */

    int min = l;
    for(int i = l+1; i <= r; i++)
    {   if(a[i] < a[min])
        {   min = i;
        }
    }

    swap(a[l], a[min]);
    sort(a, l+1, r);
}
```

You can also do it iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the intention like following

```
int check (int *v, int n){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (v[i] != -1){
            return -1;
            //break;  //This code that does not reach
        }
        //else return 1;  //move to after for-loop
    }
    return 1;
}

void ordenaVetor (int *v, int n){
    int i, k, j=0, vp[n];

    while (check(v,n) == -1){
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(v[i]<0) continue;//Element of -1 excluded. v[k] too.
            for (k=i+1; k<n; k++){
                if (v[k]>=0 &&  v[i] < v[k]) break;
            }
            if (k == n){
                vp[j] = v[i];
                v[i] = -1;
                j++;
                break;//start over
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        v[i] = vp[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an existing sort implementation instead of reinventing the wheel:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int desc(void const *a, void const *b)
{
    if ( *(int *)a < *(int *)b ) return 1;
    return -1;
}

void sortVector (int *v, int n)
{
    qsort(v, n, sizeof *v, desc);
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried that but what triggered this problem for me was that I needed to order the elements in a struct array according to the size of an int variable inside each struct. This function did not seem to work in that case. I asked this question because I could not seem to get the algorithm.

Comment: @mcpca You can still use `qsort` in that case, you just need to change the contents of the comparator function to include the logic to do the comparison.