# Order a vector in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(int *v[]) {
int tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j< 10; j++)
        if (*v[i] > *v[j]) {
            tmp = *v[i];
            *v[i] = *v[j];
            *v[j] = tmp;
        }
}

}


void main() {
int v[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("Enter the value for v[%d]: \n", i);
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}
printf("The vector is: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("Value on the position %d is %d \n", i, v[i]);

change(&v[]);                           // I think here is the problem



printf("\n\n After function call, the vector is: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("Value on the position %d is %d \n", i, v[i]);

getch();
}
```

I need to ordonate a vector but i don't know how to pass the value of a vector to a function. Can someone help me to solve this and to explain me and make me understand, this is important. Thank you guys !

Comment: Recommended reading any C book or text. See sections for functions, arrays and pointers and how to pass them. This would be easier for you to understand, than anyone answering here. This should not take much time.

Comment: Did you try change that line (where you think the prob is to:
change(v);
or change(&v)

Comment: C does not have a "vector". You mean _arrays_!

Comment: this is how my teacher call it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C: Sort vector elements in descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119553/c-sort-vector-elements-in-descending-order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void change(int *v[]) {
int *tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j< 10; j++)
        if (v[i] > v[j]) {
            tmp = v[i];
            v[i] = v[j];
            v[j] = tmp;
        }
}

}


void main() {
int *v[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("Enter the value for v[%d]: \n", i);
    scanf("%d", &v[i]);
}
printf("The vector is: \n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("Value on the position %d is %d \n", i, v[i]);

        change(v);                              



   printf("\n\n After function call, the vector is: \n");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("Value on the position %d is %d \n", i, v[i]);

_getch();
}
```

I solve ! thank you guy. This is the code if someone is 
interested

Answer (score 0):

The function must be declared like

```
void change(int v[]) {
            ^^^^^^
```

and called like

```
changes( v );
```

As result you have to change these statements

```
   if (*v[i] > *v[j]) {
        tmp = *v[i];
        *v[i] = *v[j];
        *v[j] = tmp;
```

like

```
   if ( v[i] > v[j]) {
        tmp = v[i];
        v[i] = v[j];
        v[j] = tmp;
```

The function can look like

```
void change( int v[] ) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j< 10; j++ )
        {
            if ( v[i] > v[j] ) 
            {
                int tmp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = tmp;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Take into account that it would be better if the function could deal with arrays of different sizes. In this case it must have second parameter that will specify the number of elements in the array. For example

```
void change( int v[], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( v[i] > v[j] ) 
            {
                int tmp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[j];
                v[j] = tmp;
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
change( v, 10 );
```

Comment: i need to change the value from vector, not just to print the value ordonate

Comment: @FilipLaurentiu See my updated answer. Your implementation of the bubble sort is incorrect.

Comment: @FilipLaurentiu I removed the remark about the incorrect implementation of the bubble sort because you are using some other algorithm that nevertheless works correctly. So if you made the snags I pointed out then the program will be compiled nd executed.